# Existence of solution for the IVP $ ~\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=f(x),~ y(0)=0,$ where $f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & 0 \leq x\leq1 \\0 &x >1. \end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I met with a question,

Q. Let $y(x)$ be a continuous solution of the IVP$$  ~\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=f(x),~ y(0)=0,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(*) $$ where $f(x) = \begin{cases}1 &\mbox{if }~ 0 \leq x\leq1 \\
   0 & \mbox{if }~ x >1 \end{cases}$. Then $y\left( \frac{3}{2}\right) $ is,

1. $\frac{\sin h (1)}{e^3}$
2. $\frac{\cos h (1)}{e^3}$
3. $\frac{\sin h (1)}{e^2}$
4. $\frac{\cos h (1)}{e^2}$,

I got the option 3, as the desirable by seperately solving $(*)$ on $0 \leq x <1$ and $x>1$ to get a continuous solution $$y(x)= \begin{cases}\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{2} &\mbox{if }~ 0 \leq x\leq1 \\
   \left(\frac{e^2-1}{2}\right)e^{-2x} & \mbox{if }~ x >1 \end{cases}.$$
But in this way, we have,
$y^{\prime}+2 y=f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0 & x>1\end{array}\right.,$

$\Rightarrow y^{\prime}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1-2 y & \text { for } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ -2 y & \text { for } x>1\end{array}\right.,$

$=\left\{\begin{array}{l}1-2 \left(\frac{1-e^{-2 x}}{2}\quad 0 \leq x \leq 1\right. \\ -2 x\left(\frac{e^{2}-1}{2}\right) e^{-2 x} \quad x>1\end{array}\right.$
$=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}e^{-2 x} & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ \left(1-e^{2}\right) e^{-2 x} & x>1\end{array}\right.,$

$\left.\begin{array}{rl}\Rightarrow & \lim _{x \rightarrow 1^{-}} y^{\prime}=e^{-2}>0 \ \\ & \lim _{x \rightarrow 1^+}y^{\prime}=e^{-2}-1<0\end{array}\right\}$, a jump. This is not possible since a derivative cannot have a jump discontinuity. Can the modification $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 &\mbox{if }~ 0 \leq x<1 \\
   0 & \mbox{if }~ x >1 \end{cases}$$ is a remedy? Anything wrong with my argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct, and you don't even need to compute solutions on the subintervals to see that. If $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $x=1$ then there is no differentiable function $y: [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ satisfying
$$
y'(x)+2y(x)=f(x)
$$
because that would imply that $y'$ also has a jump discontinuity. As you correctly said, that is not possible (derivatives have the intermediate value property).

So you can compute solutions on $[0, 1)$ and on $(1, \infty)$ and stitch them together to get a continuous function $y$ on $[0, \infty)$, but that's all.